# How to extract substring from string

Tags: bash, sed, grep, substring, extract

I have a string, that does not always look the same, and from this string I want to extract some information if it exists. The string might look like one of the following:

```
myCommand -s 12 moreParameters
myCommand -s12 moreParamaters
myCommand -s moreParameters
```

I want to get the number, i.e. 12 in this case, if it exists. How can I accomplish that?

Many thanks!

EDIT: There is a fourth possible value for the string:

`myCommand moreParameters`

How can I modify the regex to cover this case as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
n=$(echo "$string"|sed 's/^.*-s *\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/')
```

This will match a `-s` eventually followed by spaces and digits; and replace the whole string by the digits.

> `myCommand -s 12 moreParameters` => 12
>   `myCommand -s12 moreParamaters`  => 12
>   `myCommand -s moreParameters`    => empty string

EDIT: There is a fourth possible value for the string:

`myCommand moreParameters`

How can I modify the regex to cover this case as well?

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response. Much appreciated!

Comment: in bash, you can use "here-strings": `n=$(sed 's/^.*-s *\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/' <<< "$string")`

Comment: You can handle the additional case e.g. by only printing matching lines. `sed -n 's/^.*-s *\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/p'`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ a="myCommand -s 12 moreParameters"
$ b="myCommand -s12 moreParamaters"
$ echo $(expr "$a" : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)')
12
$ echo $(expr "$b" : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)')
12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do all these without the need for external tools

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ string="myCommand -s 12 moreParameters"
$ string="${string##*-s+( )}"
$ echo "${string%% *}"
12
```